# Interaction between semaphores and context switches

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, semaphore, scheduling

Suppose thread S called `semaphore.signal()`, while threads W1, W2 were waiting on that semaphore.

I know that the semaphore semantics provides no guarantees about the order in wihch the three threads will be scheduled. However, to understand performance implications, I wanted to figure out the behavior of the typical implementations.

Specifically (for commonly used semaphore implementations):

1. Will both W1 and W2 <strike>get the CPU</strike> be woken up, with one of them instantly discovering that it has to block again and thus going back to sleep?
2. Will S be put to sleep before it returns from the `semaphore.signal()` call? Or will it stay on the CPU as long as it would have stayed without the `signal()` call?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is underspecified.

ONE thread from W1,W2 will be set ready by the semaphore signal, call it 'W'

What happens after that is unclear because you have insufficiently specified the scheduler/dispatcher configuration and state.

If there is a free core available, S may continue to run on and W may be dispatched on to the spare core.

If there is no free core available, W may preempt S: W is dispatched on to the core that was running S, and S set ready, waiting for a core to run on.

If there is no free core available, the kernel may preempt another thread running on another core, in favour of W.  So, both S and W will run.

Specifically:

> Will both W1 and W2 get the CPU be woken up, with one of them
>   instantly discovering that it has to block again and thus going back
>   to sleep?

Why would any OS do that?  It's a whole pile of extra work for no gain.  One signal is received by the semaphore, so one thread is dequeued and set ready.  The other remains blocked and waiting in the semaphore thread queue for another signal.  There is no need to 'wake it up'.

> Will S be put to sleep before it returns from the semaphore.signal()
>   call? Or will it stay on the CPU as long as it would have stayed
>   without the signal() call?

It is not required that the signaling thread, S, leave the running state. If the OS kernel scheduling algorithm and state can run W on another core, S can just continue to run.  If S is preempted by W, then it's no longer running, and is stuck in the kernel ready queue, waiting for a core to become available. W may just become ready, not be dispatched, and S may run on.